# Strange output of embedding_lookup_sparse

Tags: tensorflow

Consider such code:

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.constant([[1., 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]))
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

st = tf.SparseTensor([[0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 1, 1],
                      [1, 0, 0],
                      [1, 1, 0],
                      [2, 0, 0],
                      [2, 1, 0]], [0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 3], [3, 3, 2])

sess.run(tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse(w, st, None, combiner='sum'))
```

Output:

```
array([[  6.,   8.],
       [  4.,   6.],
       [ 10.,  12.]], dtype=float32)
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#embedding_lookup_sparse) the shape of output must be [3, 3, 3], since shape(sp_id) = [3, 3, 2] and shape(w) = [4, 3], but it doesn't :(

Can someone explain why it works in this way? Because I expected behavior simple embedding_lookup, but with aggregation on the last axes..

**EDIT**

For each object I have 2 features and each represent by one word, since that I want represent each object with two concat embeddings, I can do this by:

```
sess.run(tf.reshape(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(w, [[0, 1], [2, 3]]), shape=(2, 4)))
```

Output

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.]], dtype=float32)
```

So, now I still have 2 features, but each one can be represent with several words, and I want to aggregate embeddings for words corresponding to one feature. It looks like embedding_lookup_sparse should work in such way, but I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output in the second case?

Comment: I expect `[ [[1, 2], [3, 4]], 
                 [[1, 2], [1, 2]],  
                 [[1, 2], [1, 2]] ]`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the lookup, you will get a tensor which has the size of the vector in the embedding, so the output innermost dimension has to be 2. For instance, if you used:

`w = tf.Variable(tf.constant(
   [[1., 2, 0.1, 0.2], [3, 4, 0.3, 0.4], [5, 6, 0.5, 0.6], [7, 8, 0.7, 0.8]]))`

then you would get an output with 4 inner columns.